# Google sheet, Query, Data range from a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want a query where I can change the data range from a cell.

CEL A1: Data!A1:E1000

CEL A2: SELECT * where  A>100

What I want:

```
=QUERY(A1;A2)
```

Right now this only work when I do

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:E1000;A2)
```

Question:
How can I get my data range what is in a Cell

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(A1);A2)
```